# How to make iter method of a class return a value without running the for loop?

Tags: python, dataframe, memory-management, iteration, yield

I have a class, which has got an `__iter__` method, which goes like this

```
class Mycorpus:
    
    '''This class helps us to train the model without loading the whole dataset to the RAM.'''
    
    def __init__(self, filepath= text_file):
        self.filepath = filepath
        
    def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.filepath,'r') as rfile:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(rfile, delimiter=',')
            for row in csv_reader:
        
                # splitter splits the conversation into client and agent part
                client_convo, agent_convo = convo_split.splitter(row['Combined'])

                client_tokens = preprocess(client_convo)
                agent_tokens = preprocess(agent_convo)
                
                yield client_tokens
```

I am passing this object to a function which requires this object to return one set of tokens at a time when itered. ie, either a `client_tokens` or a `agent_tokens`. I want the `__iter__` to yield one `client_tokens` and on the next iteration the `agent_tokens` from the same client agent pair. I don't want to yield two set of tokens together as it will break the functionality. Only one at a time. My main objective here is to avoid looping through the file twice and using splitter function on the same conversations again.

I have tried doing something like below.

```
def __init__(self, filepath= text_file):
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.agent_turn = 0

def __iter__(self):
        with open(self.filepath,'r') as rfile:
            csv_reader = csv.DictReader(rfile, delimiter=',')
 
            if self.agent_turn:
                self.agent_turn = 0
                yield agent_tokens
            
            else:
                for row in csv_reader:
                
                    # splitter splits the conversation into client and agent part
                    client_convo, agent_convo = convo_split.splitter(row['Combined'])

                    client_tokens = preprocess(client_convo)
                    agent_tokens = preprocess(agent_convo)
                    self.agent_turn = 1
                    yield client_tokens
```

But the above code is only giving `client_tokens`.
Is there a better way of doing this without using entire dataset to memory? Is my requirement even possible using `__iter__` method? Any help or direction is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use two yield statements, just as many examples show you.  Remember that a generator / iterator reenters after the `yield` statement, not at the top of the function.

```
        for row in csv_reader:
    
            # splitter splits the conversation into client and agent part
            client_convo, agent_convo = convo_split.splitter(row['Combined'])

            client_tokens = preprocess(client_convo)
            agent_tokens = preprocess(agent_convo)
            
            yield client_tokens
            yield agent_tokens
```

Comment: Doesn't this gonna return two tokens in one iteration itself? I need one set of tokens per iteration. I am using it for gensim word2vec training, which requires the a single iteration yield a single set of tokens.

Comment: @Jihjohn - write a simple toy example with two or more yields then iterate over it to test. As stated in the answer `Remember that a generator / iterator reenters after the yield statement, not at the top of the function.`

Comment: In general, don't ask SO what will happen if you execute a particular code sequence -- run it and see.  The Python run-time system is the final authority on what happens.  :-)

Comment: Sorry guys. I ran it and it works fine. Thank you @Prune

Comment: It seems that you need to back up a step and work through a tutorial on generators.  Please do so.  If you're still confused afterward, then perhaps you'll have a new SO question to post.  Feel free to ping me in a comment so I'll come to look at that new problem.

Comment: @prune got it. I miss interpreted the statement `a generator / iterator reenters after the yield statement, not at the top of the function`. All clear now. Thank you. I'll take a tutorial anyway

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out.
I'm still working tutorials, myself ... after seven years using this language.